# How to install ios 8 sdk on xcode 5?

Tags: ios8, xcode5

I have OS X Mountain Lion (10.8.5) and Xcode 5.1 already installed on my mac and i can't upgrade my os for now. I need ios 8 sdk in order to publish my app in app store.

How can i install ios 8 sdk on xcode 5?

I have tried copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/8.0/ from another computer but it doesn't work - new sdk is not presented in Build Settings > Base SDK combo box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly that's not possible: the iOS 8 SDK is only available with Xcode 6, for which you need either Mavericks or Yosemite. Furthermore, since February 1st 2015 you can no longer submit apps to the App Store using Xcode 5: https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=10202014a

If you can't upgrade your current system at the moment, look into Parallels Desktop and install a virtual instance of your Mac from the recovery partition. You can then upgrade the VM and install Xcode 6 there, without having to upgrade your current system.

Alternatively, use ShirtPocket's SuperDuper to clone your current hard disk to an external one, then boot from the external drive and upgrade that to Yosemite and Xcode 6.